# List commits that are reachable by following the parent links from the given commit (like `git rev-list`)

Tags: git, f#, libgit2sharp

Is there a way to list all commits that are reachable from HEAD using `libgit2sharp` library like `git rev-list HEAD` do?

There is a function `ReferenceCollectionException.ReachableFrom`, but it returns the list of refs pointed at particular commit:

```
let repo = new Repository("C:\path\to\repo")
let c = repo.Lookup<Commit>("HEAD")
let commits = repo.Refs.ReachableFrom([c])
```

And `commits` contains only 4 elements:

```
[ refs/heads/vNext => "63f8d6d90f06f4578604b57502f2c6b8aabf4479"
, refs/remotes/origin/HEAD => refs/remotes/origin/vNext => "63f8d6d90f06f4578604b57502f2c6b8aabf4479"
, refs/remotes/origin/ntk/issue_953 => "d5ced8c64e5ea9f6ba2135a72d59da2208215c6c"
, refs/remotes/origin/vNext => "63f8d6d90f06f4578604b57502f2c6b8aabf4479"
]
```

But there are much more nested parents commits of `HEAD`:

```
>> git rev-list HEAD | wc -l
1730
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code should help you accomplish what you're after

```cs
var filter = new CommitFilter { Since = repo.Head };

foreach (var commit in repo.Commits.QueryBy(filter))
{
    Console.WriteLine(commit.Sha);
}
```